# When I use group_concat on two fields, can I count on the two concatenations having the same order?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, group-concatenation

If I have a table like this:

```
  bagid  fruit  color
  -----  -----  -----
  1      apple  red
  1      banana yellow
```

and I select `bagid`,GROUP_CONCAT(`fruit`),GROUP_CONCAT(`color`) grouped by bagid, can I count on the results looking like this:

```
1 apple,banana red,yellow
```

or will they sometimes look like this:

```
1 apple,banana yellow,red
```

In other words, will the two concatenations always be ordered in the same way? That seems to be the case, but I'd like to be sure.  For what it's worth, I'm using Mariadb 10.3.

Comment: Consider, as a single column, `GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(fruit, ' - ', color))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not guaranted that they will be in the same order, eventhogh it likely will happen. Not even adding an `ORDER BY` at the end of your query will guarantee it, since that is logically evaluated after the aggregate functions.

You can however get the same order if you add the same order by to both `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT bagid
     , GROUP_CONCAT(fruit ORDER BY fruit)
     , GROUP_CONCAT(color ORDER BY fruit) 
FROM t
GROUP BY bagid
```

Comment: Ahh! Of course. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Why is that not guaranteed (assuming the `ORDER BY` is deterministic)?